# Intercepted part of y-axis

Tags: geometry

Find the length of the intercepted part if the $y$-axis of the straight line whose equation is
$$\frac{y-1}{x}=1$$
The answer: We can write the equation as
$$y=x+1 $$ then at $x=0 $, $y=1$.
So the length of the intercepted part equals $1$.
But if we put $x = 0$ in the original formula we get $y$ is undefined. 
So which answer is correct ?

Comment: As you noted, $0$ is not in the domain of the original function, so our line is in fact the line $y = x+1$ with an open point at $(0,1)$

Comment: Some one says when we form the equation of the straight that passes through the points (0,1) and (1,2), we say the equation is $$\frac{y-1}{x-0}= 1$$ and this equation is the original equation so we get the intecepted part is 1

Answer (score 1):

Any nonzero expression divided by $ 0 $ is always going to be undefined. The rational function $$ \frac{y - 1}{x} $$ is not defined when $ x = 0 $. You are right that the $y$-coordinate of the $y$-intercept when $ x = 0 $ is $ y = 1 $, but since that rational function is undefined at that $x$-value there is a removable discontinuity (an open, unshaded hole) at the point $ (0, 1) $.